# I lost an Xcode Project

Tags: xcode, project, simulator, recover

Is there any way I can recover a deleted Xcode Project? One night I was making updates and the next morning the whole project was gone. Couldn't find it in the recycling bin or anywhere. The project was synced in my iCloud drive.

The app still runs in the simulator. Is this a good sign? Thanks for any help!

Comment: So I assume you neither have TimeMachine active nor do you use any version control like git? If it was synced via iCloud then use the restore option on the website.

Comment: Please try reopen project from recent, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/objc/opening-reopening-and-closing-projects.html

Comment: @aBilal17 since it was deleted from local disk, I suppose you can't open recent project that way.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you can't.

Well, if it was sync to iCloud drive, then you can get it back from iCloud (I think so, since I never use that feature to backup). The app in your simulator doesn't help, since the code there was already compiled to machine code and unable to extract back to your original code.

Next time, make sure you have backup methods, like using source control (git, svn...) or zip and clone to drive. Good luck. Sorry for your lost, I know that feeling.